# Does '頑張って' affect '仕事' using 'を' in 留学を決心した上は、**仕事を頑張って**留学の代金を貯金すべきだ。?

Tags: particles, transitivity

留学を決心した上は、**仕事を頑張って**留学の代金を貯金すべきだ。

1. 頑張って is Intransitive verb so why would it be related to 仕事? I thought it had to be 仕事に not 仕事を.
2. If the verb of 仕事を is not 頑張って , then where is its verb in the sentence (i don't think it's すべき nor だ)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

頑張る is an intransitive verb, but it can also be used as a transitive verb, at least in current Japanese. (I think this is a rather new usage.) According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> がんばる【頑張る】
> （語法）他動詞としても使う。「英語の勉強**をがんばって**一番になったこともある」

Comment: So does it mean that both 仕事に and 仕事を can be used or just  仕事を?

Comment: I think 仕事に頑張る is also acceptable. 「仕事で頑張る」とも言うかも。